# efficiently copying iterator output to a slice of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to copy the results of itertools combinations to a slice of an existing numpy array.
The code below works but I wanted to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this as I will be repeating this millions of times for a simulation.

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np


A=[2,5,7,3,100,8]
B=np.zeros((20,20),dtype=np.uint8)

numsims = 1

for i in range (numsims):
    combs = list(combinations(A,3))
    B[0:3,0:20]=np.array(combs).T

print (B)
```

Comment: What kind of improvement do you expect?  where?  What's the slow part of that expression?  Have you timed individual part of the assignment?

Comment: You are never using `i`. So the trivial optimization would be to leave out the loop :D

Comment: In my real program  "i" would be in millions

Comment: @hpaulj 
here is a part of the profile output for 1 million iterations.  Most of the time seems to be lost in creating the intermediate array so a way to do this without requiring to create an intermediate array would be lot more efficient. Tried nested for loops but its even slower. 
    7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(allocate_lock)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(append)
  1000001   10.893    0.000   10.893    0.000 :0(array)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(copy)

Comment: The tuples of numbers have to be converted an array at some point or other.  `B[:20,:3]=list(combinations...)` probably has the same time (with a hidden `np.array` call).

Comment: Sometimes `np.fromiter(gen , int)` is faster, but only for a flat number generator.  You  are generating tuples, so using `fromiter` is harder and slower.